# How to replace (&lt: &gt;) as (< >) in SOAP response using java?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, encoding

I have SOAP request and response. please look at below response :,

```
SOAP Response snippet :


[CDATA [ &lt ; tag &gt; value for response &gt ; &lt; /tag> < /return>

I have String object in java code and i am returning it using 

import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Use;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

 -------
------
-------

Return String;
```

I want to remove above highlighted data using Java code and want to execute Response like below :

< return> < tag> value for response < /tag> < /return>

```
How to remove 
1) < &gt ; &lt;
2) [CDATA [[
```

Please give resolution for removing not required characters in Java code,so i can get the proper response ?

Please share any of the useful example

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you will have to return that string like this...

```
return "<<![CDATA[< return> < tag> value for response < /tag> < /return>]]>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Servlet Filter which intercepts and wraps the HttpServletResponse, and convert those characters.

However, you shouldn't need to do that - I think it points to a problem elsewhere in your architecture. Assuming that SOAP isn't a critical design choice, I would strongly consider using Jersey + Jackson and producing a REST API rather than a SOAP one.